# Can my "view by category" jquery code be shortened or refined?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, categories

I am attempting to update my photography website and use jquery to show or hide the "categories" for my portfolio.  I've searched all over an finally came up with this solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/145/

It works OK.  When you click a button for a category, it hides the rest and shows that category.  However, is the code too messy or can be shortened?  Do any of you code ninjas know if it is legit or can be slimmed down?

I am mainly concerned with the way I hide other categories.  For each function, I list out all of the other categories one by one an 'show' the category you clicked on.  So if a user clicks "portrait" I first show the portrait class and then hide all other classes (landscape, personal, etc) one by one.  If I add a category down the road I'll have to update each function.  Not a big deal, just wanting to make sure there isn't a better way and that my code looks good and will not cause any memory problems from me being absolutely new at jquery.

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

P.S. If any real jedis want to look at another thing that only slightly bothers me; right now, each div fades away almost one after another.  Is there a way to pause or something and have them all fade away more in unison?  I hope that makes sense.  I just would like (if at all possible) for them to animate away together instead of collapsing quickly one by one like dominos.  O.K.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can cache the categories.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.post').hide() // or $('.post').hide()
    $('.' + this.id).show(500);
});

$('#showall').click(function() {
    $('.post').show(500);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/148/)

Comment: Yep I was thinking about it `:P` +1 `:)`

Comment: Removed my post, No worries bruv!

Comment: Thank you!  Worked like a champ and what a quick reply...  I wish I had enough reputation to vote you up.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the categories, instead of trying to find them each time.

```
document.ready(function() {
     var Wedding = $('.wedding');
});
```

For the second problem you need to use a callback function, as a parameter.
The callback function executes only after the main function has finished.

Example:

```
 $('div').click(function() {
      $(this).animate({'top': '50px'}, 500, function() {
           //callback - start
           $(this).text('a');
           //callback-end
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I really like the code by 'undefined' above.  Short, sweet, and works great.  If I run into problems with his code, I'll look at yours!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/M4G4r/

Put the buttons inside toggles.
Put the elements inside .posts
Make sure "portraits" maps to correct ones with "s"

**Happy Coding :)**

```
$('.toggles button').click(function(){
    var d_id = this.id;
    var obj_cur = $('.posts .' + d_id);

    $('.post').not( obj_cur ).hide(500);
    obj_cur.show(500);
});
```

Comment: Tip: move the buttons on top so it wont look like its bouncing. mark button as BOLD or some marker so you know which is active.

Comment: Good call on the bold and placement.  I am actually going to have the categories be graphical buttons that will animate and be at the top.  I just threw buttons in for the example.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: yeah, being a photography site, I'm sure you got plans already for those stuff.

Comment: make sure to use correct selective css like ".toggles button"  and ".posts .post" so other tags wont get affected.